# Не запускается отладка в Visual Studio на Mac. Кнопка светиться серым

Tags: c#

Не могу запустить код. Кнопка отладки горит серым, горячие клавиши тоже не работают. Операционная система - Mac

- Много раз переустанавливала visual studio, но это не помогло
- Пыталась обновить .Net, но выдает ошибку
- Вне зависимости какой я файл создаю (.net core, .net 6, .net 7) отладку запустить не получается.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Что делать

Comment: `Что делать ` - наверно перейти по [ссылке](http://aka.ms/vs/mac/net-6-arm-sdk-migration), которую вам указала студия, прочитать и сделать все то, что там указано?

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы спасли меня от отчисления. Я идиот!!!